# How to test GCM server side without implementing client side?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have created the server side for gcm using the code below:

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, MESSAGE_VALUE).build();

        MulticastResult result = null;
        try
        {

         result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
         System.out.println(result.toString());

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It is working fine but the problem i am facing is that currently i can't implement the client side,so i don't have the registration id to test my code.
So anyone can please help me that is there any way to test my gcm server side implementation without implementing client side ??? Thanks ..!!!!

Comment: Check out the client side code for gcm here: https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android/gcm-demo. Also i notice that you are using old deprecated server side code, you can check out the newest here:https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/client-libraries/java/rest-client

Comment: have you tried sending to a topic?